# Clean data after testing

Tags: testing, go

I write tests and in this tests I work with some saved data files, DB records etc.

Should I remove this data before test ends?

For example, I check `user` finder

```
func (ID int) User (*User) {
  // my finder here
}
```

before test I have to create `User` to DB. So, should I do something like

```
defer db.Clean()
```

???

same with files `*os.File`

Comment: It's up to you. If the test data are useless, why not delete them? And doing it after the test with defer is a good idea.

Comment: Dockerize your database with a set of test data. When the tests are finished you can just delete the container.

Answer (score 1):

So that we are all on the same page, there are a number of different forms of testing. Here we will consider unit testing and integration testing.

If you are unit testing, I would expect the use of mocks only, and no interaction with files. So I assume this is for some kind of integration testing.

[This is a link](https://speakerdeck.com/mitchellh/advanced-testing-with-go?slide=28) to a bunch of slides, from a talk in testing by mitchellh the founder and CTO of hashicorp

One of the methods described in this talk is returning a `func()` closure that's responsible for cleaning up afterwards.

You can encapsulate all your setup logic into a function that returns a cleanup closure.

```
func SetupIntegrationDB(t *testing.T, addr string) (*sql.DB, func()) {
    // setup the connection, use t.Fatal for all errors.

    cleanup := func() {
        // here you have access to both t, and *sql.DB
        // you can do all the clean up required, 
        // and return this anonymous function to be called later
    }

    return db, cleanup
}


// inside your test
db, cleanup := SetupIntegrationDB(t, addr)
defer cleanup()
```

This is very similar to what you suggested in your question, but allows for slightly improved encapsulation of the cleanup logic. All your tests just need to execute the cleanup function they are given, and not care about how it's done.

This same pattern can be used for files, returning the file (or an `io.Writer`), and a function that knows where that file exists and can delete that file later on.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about unit testing your code, then there should be no call to the db. You should be using an interface that you can stub or mock.

Comment: what about files? For example I create file, write to this file data and then compress it. What I have to do with file?

Comment: I would create an interface to write data to a file. So that I can stub this as well and make sure my overall functionality is working. I will then write a unit test for testing if the file is being written and compressed.